# Data structure for incremental KNN (IKNN) search over high-dimensional vectors

Tags: data-structures, search-algorithms, nearest-neighbour

I have a database $D$ of n-dimensional numerical vectors, and I want to do an incremental KNN (IKNN) search over the vectors in $D$. More precisely, given a query vector $v_q \in D$ I need to find $k$ vectors $v_i \in D \setminus \{v_q\}$ sorted by value of $Euclidean(v_q, v_i)$ from low to high where $Euclidean(v_q, v_i)$ is a function that computes the Euclidean distance between $v_q$ and $v_i$. In short, I need to find $k$ vectors with lower values of their distances to $v_q$ ascendingly. Contrary to normal KNN search, in my problem, the value of $k$ is not known before the search starts. A the start, $k$ is initialized to $x$ then $k$ nearest neighbours are fetched, now if the boolean variable $c$ is true, the search terminates, otherwise the search expands, and $d$ other closer vectors are fetched. The expansion continues until either $c$ becomes true or each vector in the database has been fetched.

The pseudo code of what I want to do is shown below:

```
// IKKN search
k=x // intilizing k to x
knn_set = {} // knn results
while (c != true or |knn_set| < |D|) {
Add k vectors with lower distances to query vector to knn_set---if they are not already in knn_set 
k = k + d // expanding k by d
}
```

Now, I'm trying to find a data structure that could be used for IKNN search over n-dimensional numerical vectors. By the way, assuming $n=4$, as an example, a vector can look like something like this: $(1.0, -4.14, 0.2, 0.9)$.

I'd appreciate any answers or suggestions.

Comment: Most data structures for nearest-neighbor search should be adaptable to this.  What ones have you considered, and what have you come up with?  How large is the dimension? ($n$)

Comment: I'm thinking about using a KD-tree or an R-tree. And n=16, but it can be as large as about twice that (ie, n=32).